# Mockito InvalidUseOfMatchersException when mocking a post request

Tags: java, java-8, mockito, junit4

I'm totally new to mockito and I have tried a lot of solutions I found online but I still can't solve this problem. I'm not even sure what is causing it. I need to create a mock test for a very mature code which I am not allowed to change. The part of the code which I need to mock sends a post request to a server. I have recreated the code in a much simpler way but unfortunately, it is still rather long. Lets say I have ClassA which calls the api as shown bellow and returns an integer.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyWebTarget;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class ClassA {

    public int moveActual(String path) throws IOException {
        Response wsResponse = null;
        String newHome = "0" ;
        ResteasyClient httpClient = new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(1)
                .establishConnectionTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).socketTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = httpClient.target(path) ;

        Map<String, Object> request = new HashMap<>();
        request.put("operation", "dislocation");
        request.put("direction", "right");
        request.put("amount", "2");
        request.put("unit", "metric");
        String requestJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(request);

        wsResponse = target.request().post(Entity.entity(requestJson, "application/json"));
        String responseString = wsResponse.readEntity(String.class);
        ObjectMapper responseMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>) responseMapper.readValue(responseString, Map.class);

        if (response != null) {
            newHome = (String) response.get("coordinate");
        }
        // In the real code there is much more code here.
        return Integer.parseInt(newHome) ;
    }
}
```

I need to mock the server to test the moveActual method. So I decided to mock the post method. In order to do that, I came up with the test below:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyWebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import externalTests.ClassA;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DispositionMockTest {

    @Mock
    ResteasyWebTarget targetMock;

    @InjectMocks
    ClassA classA;

    @Test
    public void dispositionTest() throws Exception {
        // Given
        Map<String, Integer> outcomeMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>() ;
        outcomeMap.put("coordinate", 4) ;
        Response resp = Response.status(Status.OK).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(outcomeMap).build() ;
        given(targetMock.request().post(ArgumentMatchers.isA(Entity.class))).willReturn(resp) ;

        // When
        int result = classA.moveActual("url") ;

        // Then
        assertEquals(4, result);
    }

}
```

However, I get the error bellow no matter what I do.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at externalTests.DispositionMockTest.dispositionTest(DispositionMockTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:77)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:83)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at externalTests.DispositionMockTest.dispositionTest(DispositionMockTest.java:42)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$2.testFinished(DefaultInternalRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testFinished(SynchronizedRunListener.java:56)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$7.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestFinished(RunNotifier.java:187)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.EachTestNotifier.fireTestFinished(EachTestNotifier.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:77)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:83)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

I have tried `@spy` instead of `@mock` and other matchers like `ArgumentMatchers.any(Entity.class)` and `ArgumentMatchers.any()` but to no avail. I was looking into powermock but none of the methods and classes involved are private, nor static. I have no idea what else to try. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mocked `ResteasyWebTarget` and didn't define what should be the return of `request()` method, you got that exception.

You should first mock request and return it to the `request()` method and define the behavior to `post()` method from `mockedRequest`

```
when(targetMock.request()).thenReturn(mockedRequest);
when(mockedRequest.post(any(Entity.class))).thenReturn(resp) ;
```

Comment: Oh! Ok, let me try and be back. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, sorry for being away for this long. I tested a million different stuff. The only thing that works is to change the annotation to `@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)`. But that just solved the null pointer exception. What you wrote also seems to be correct, but I can't find a way to mock request. No matter what I do I get different errors from resteasy itself. So, one obstacle down. Another ahead!

Comment: Since the problem now is more of a resteasy problem I posted it in a new question with the updated code. I appreciate it if you can have a look. Here is the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158437/mocking-a-post-request-using-mockito-raises-javax-ws-rs-processingexception-res

Comment: @mnsr Okay let me check that

Comment: @mnsr I have posted a solution, tell me if it's working :)