# Mocking a post request using Mockito raises javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request

Tags: junit, java-8, mocking, mockito, resteasy

I'm totally new to Mockito and I need to mock a post request so that I can test a client alone. However, no matter what I do I get the `RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request` exception. This is the simplified version of what I have so far. I have the class TestClassA which sends a post request to an api as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyWebTarget;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestClassA {

    public int moveActual(String path) throws IOException {

        Response resp = null;
        String newHome = "0" ;
        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        ResteasyWebTarget callTarget = client.target(path) ;

        Map<String, Object> request = new HashMap<>();
        request.put("operation", "dislocation");
        request.put("direction", "right");
        request.put("amount", "2");
        request.put("unit", "metric");
        String payload = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(request);

        resp = callTarget.request().post(Entity.entity(payload, "application/json"));
        String outcome = resp.readEntity(String.class);
        ObjectMapper outcomeMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> finalResponse = (Map<String, Object>) outcomeMapper.readValue(outcome, Map.class);

        if (finalResponse != null) {
            newHome = (String) finalResponse.get("coordinate");
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(newHome) ;
    }
}
```

I try to mock the post request using the mockito test bellow:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Answers;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyWebTarget;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import externalTests.TestClassA;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DispositionMockTest {

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    ResteasyWebTarget targetMock;

    @InjectMocks
    TestClassA classA;


    @Test
    public void dispositionTest() throws Exception {
        // Given
        Map<String, Integer> outcomeMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>() ;
        outcomeMap.put("coordinate", 4) ;
        Response resp = Response.status(Status.OK).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(outcomeMap).build() ;

        //  Builder req = DispositionMockTest.fakeRequest() ;
        //  given(req.post(ArgumentMatchers.any(Entity.class))).willReturn(fakeRequest()) ;

        given(targetMock.request().post(ArgumentMatchers.any(Entity.class))).willReturn(resp) ;

        // When
        int result = classA.moveActual("url to what has to run") ;

        // Then
        assertEquals(4, result);
    }
}
```

I also tried to mock the request method using the two commented out lines in the test and have it return more or less fake Builder from the method bellow.

```
public static Builder fakeRequest() {
    ResteasyClient httpClient = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget target = httpClient.target("");
    Builder req = target.request() ;
    return req ;
}
```

But I keep getting this exception.

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:325)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:443)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:62)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:219)
    at externalTests.TestClassA.moveActual(TestClassA.java:33)
    at externalTests.DispositionMockTest.dispositionTest(DispositionMockTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:77)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:83)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:187)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:320)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultRoutePlanner.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.determineRoute(InternalHttpClient.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    ... 36 more
```

I tried many possible solutions I found online but I can't get anything to work. If anyone knows how I can mock a post request I would be truly thankful to learn from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whoever may need it. I couldn't find a way to get it done using mockito. I had to move to wiremock. In wiremock you just record a successful transaction, create a wiremock server object, and have it mock the recorded behavior. Much easier and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mocked `ResteasyWebTarget` and didn't define what should be the return of `request()` method, you got that exception.

You should first mock request and return it to the `request()` method and define the behavior to `post()` method from `mockedRequest`

```
@Mock
private Invocation.Builder mockedRequest;

@Test
public void dispositionTest() throws Exception {
    when(targetMock.request()).thenReturn(mockedRequest);
    when(mockedRequest.post(any(Entity.class))).thenReturn(resp) ;
}
```

[WebTarget request() doc](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-rc-1/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html#request())

[Invocation.Builder doc](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-rc-1/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html)

Comment: The problem is that if I want to mock request, I have to define a value for all the internal variables. Some of these I have access to like ssl, but some are managed internally by resteasy. When request is mocked, the variables which are managed internally are set to mock default values. For example to an empty list. Which in turn raises an exception at some point. Even if I don't spy it. I spent about a full day trying to handle these to no avail. I'm sure I'm missing something but about a couple of hours after I posted this, I discovered wiremock which did the job in about half an hour!